# If I play Mario Kart DS on a 3DS, will WiFi multiplayer still be available?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, mario-kart-ds

I've had a DSi for almost an entire year now, and on May 20th of this year, Nintendo discontinued WiFi and multiplayer matchmaking on games.

> As of May 20, 2014, certain online functionality offered through Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection is no longer accessible. The discontinued services include online play, matchmaking and leaderboards for many Wii, Nintendo DS and Nintendo DSi games.

However, as far as I know, the Nintendo 3ds has WiFi functionality. If I played Mario Kart DS on a 3DS, would I be able to play multiplayer Mario Kart DS, or are the services discontinued for the entire game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For online multiplayer, unfortunately no.

All DS titles use the old matchmaking system.  Even though the system itself is a 3DS, the game will still attempt to connect to the old servers, which are no longer operational.

Local multiplayer should continue working.

Comment: Side note: Mario Kart 7 for the 3DS should still work online.

Comment: It should yes. Hopefully the 3DS servers will last for longer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's worth mentioning that there is now a way to play online for Nintendo DS games using an unofficial, alternate server called [Wiimmfi](https://wiimmfi.de). As long as you have a WEP WiFi connection (not a WPA WiFi connection), you can connect using Wiimmfi by setting your primary DNS server (in WiFi settings) to 164.132.44.106. See [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Sh0AZR-tKwM) for more information.